# Symfony2 - production - error in bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am using Symfony2 dev-master. Today they had the merge conflict message in PHP, which resulted in a PHP syntax error, but after they fixed it, I am still experiencing various issues with my project.

Suddenly the production environment always throws a fatal error due to bootstrap.php.cache.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'typeParser' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in project_path/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2674
```

I have tried to rebuild the file, the same way the composer does, but I cannot get rid of this error. Dev environment works. Anyone has any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: did you clear the cache after rebuilding?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, the composer does the same too.

Comment: ok, because by default composer clears the cache for the dev environment (runs this command `cache:clear --no-warmup`).  so i was just checking that you manually did if for the prod environment (`cache:clear --env=prod`)

Comment: The cache:clear command executed by composer is dev-environment only by default, like Sehael explained.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I know it only clears cache for dev environment, and I cleared the cache for production, but it does not help.